fastai integrated with Palantir Foundry
This maybe an issue but i'm trying to build fastai models in Palantirs foundry.
It seems like the imports to everything doesn't work like they should.
URLs seems to have an issue, I'm just not sure if foundry supports fastai.
My question is what experience working with foundry work either with fastai,
pytorch, tensorflow etc.
import -Uqq fastbooks
